# SQL More rows with the same ID but one different column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I am trying to replicate several rows where we have id_product, id category and position (irrelevant, it can just stay 0). I want these rows to have identical id_product but with a different id_category but it keeps telling me I am making a syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO `category_product` (col1, '143', 0)
SELECT col1 FROM category_product.id_product WHERE id_category = 12;
```

I am using MariaDB / PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: `insert into t (c1, c2, c3) select col1, '143', 0  from...`

Comment: @jarlh I figured if I did a select on all three it'd have screwed it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use insert select.
selecting also the constant values

```
    INSERT INTO `category_product` (col1, id_product, position)
    SELECT col1 , '143',0
    FROM category_product

    where category_product.id_product WHERE id_category = 12;
```